# How to get "name" from module when using "import module as name"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't seem to find where the actual name that a module has been bound to is stored. For example:

```
import re as my_re

print my_re.__name__ # Output is "re," not "my_re"
```

I would like to be able to get the name that I imported the module as rather than the actual name of the module.

My use case is that I have a function that takes a function object as an argument and needs to be able to determine what name it is bound to. Here is a more thorough example:

```
import module as my_module

def my_func(in_func):
    print in_func.__bound-name__ # Or something to this effect

my_func(my_module.function1) # Should print "my_module.function1"
```

Comment: When you run `print my_re.__name__`, you already know the actual name is my_re because that is how you call the command

Comment: Right, but in my case, I have a function that takes a module as an argument, and I need to determine the name the module was imported as dynamically. I should have been more clear about that in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the module name as string and then use globals() to fetch the module for use within the function. Suppose you pass 'np' to the function, then globals()['np'] will return the function.

```
In [22]: import numpy as np
In [23]: def demo(A):
    ...:     a = globals()[A]
    ...:     print(a.array([i for i in range(10)]))
    ...:

In [24]: demo('np')
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: broken though if you do `import numpy as np; a = b = c = np` -- OP is most likely asking for something that's not a good idea ;)

Comment: fair enough. It's not a good idea to use globals() anyway. But that's the only work around I can think of. Or maybe the OP can set the __repr__ (I'm not sure)

Comment: That's an interesting option and not too far off of something that I had experimented with earlier. It seems like there should be some place where that mapping (between the actual module name and an alias) must be stored... That is what I am really hoping to find.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do exactly what you want because string `my_re` is not stored anywhere, it is only a name of a variable. [PEP221](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/#id6) which proposed the syntax for `import ... as` statement explains that the following lines are equal:

```
import re as my_re
```

and

```
import re
my_re = re
del re
```